# How can I put Pyramid in front of a PHP website using the same webserver?

Tags: php, python, apache, mod-wsgi, pyramid

The scenario is: I current have an old website that runs on PHP. Over time, that code has become hacked up and messy. It's due for a rewrite. However, I don't have time to do that rewrite yet. But I'd like to plan for it in the future.

What I need to do now is add a 'welcome' type page to the website. I'd like to code that in Python using the Pyramid framework.

The old sites URL structure is this:

```
http://website.com/XXXXXX
```

Where the `X` is the short URL id.

What I was thinking of doing was using Apaches `LocationMatch` config to catch the short URL. Something like:

```
<LocationMatch "/^([a-zA-Z0-9]{6})$">
```

This would then redirect the request to the PHP portion of the website. Everything else would be caught by Pyramid.

I'm not sure how to action this. Does Apache have an `else` type clause for `LocationMatch`? How would I tell it to serve the PHP files for `/XXXXXX` matches and send everything else to Pyramid?

Server Notes:

- Apache2 + PHP (Debian package)
- mod_wsgi 3.3
- Python2.7

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about Apache configuration, but you could use wphp, a wsgi middleware for serving php.

http://pythonpaste.org/wphp/

Comment: Thanks for the link. I'm not too familiar with how WSGI middleware works, but, it seems the request would go `apache > wsgi > php` as opposed to `apache > php`. Would this method have any noticable affect (speed, stability)? Granted, the site doesn't get heavy traffic... But still

Comment: I've never used this middleware, I am just aware of its existence. I would say: if you do not find other obvious solution, try this, and if you have performance issues, try to find something else.

Answer (score 0):

Use recipes for using AddHandler described in:

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationGuidelines#The_Apache_Alias_Directive

Apply the AddHandler and the rewrite rule to your DocumentRoot directory. Then add the SCRIPT_NAME fixup to your WSGI script file.